# How do I plot this logarithm without a "while True" loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to plot the twelve tone scale, from the lowest to the highest audible pitch, in hertz.

I found a way to do this using a while loop that is always true and then use break to exit the loop once the pitch is either lower or higher than the audible human range.

I know that this kind of loop is bad practice, but--as a novice programmer--I can't think of how to do this the proper way. How can I achieve the same result without using "while True"?

I have tried putting the condition "note > highest or note < lowest" where "True" is currently in the while loop, but then "note" is only defined within the loop so I get a "NameError: name 'note' is not defined" error.

```py
highest = 20000
lowest = 20

key = 440
TET = 12

equal_temper = [key]

i = 1
while True:
  note = key * (2**(1/TET))**i
  if note > highest or note < lowest:
    break
  equal_temper.append(note)
  i += 1

i = 1
while True:
  note = key * (2**(1/TET))**-i
  if note > highest or note < lowest:
    break
  equal_temper.append(note)
  i += 1

equal_tempered = sorted(equal_temper)
for i in range(len(equal_temper)):
  print(equal_tempered[i])
```

The output to the terminal seems to be correct. It may round down or up differently than other tables I have seen. I just want to know how to do this without using "while True."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice you're making your compiler re-make the same calculations over and over again while they only need to be done once! (And  they can be done by you).

You have a set equation for your note value: `note = key * ( 2 ** (1/TET) ) ** i`. This can easily be inverted to solve for `i` as a function of `note`: `i = TET * log_2(note / key)`. With this, and knowing your upper and lower bounds for note, we can determine the bounds for `i`.

Plugging in your upper limit, `20000` gives `i=66.07`. Anything above this will result in a note greater than your upper limit, so we want to take the floor of this value. `i_upper = 66`.

Plugging in your lower limit, `20`, gives `i=-53.51`. Anything lower than this will give a note lower than your lower limit, so we want to take the ceiling of this value. `i_lower = -53`

Now all we have to do is loop from `i_lower` to `i_upper` and fill your array with the note values.

This method avoids using while loops, is easily generalized if you change any of the parameters, and just through construction, returns a sorted array so you don't have to sort it afterwards.

```py
import math

highest = 20000
lowest = 20

key = 440
TET = 12

def note_value(key, TET, i):
    """ Returns the note value for a given key, TET, and i"""
    return key * (2**(1/TET))**i

def i_value(key, TET, N):
    """ The inverse of note_value. Re-arranged to solve for i."""
    return TET * math.log(N/key) / math.log(2)

notes_above = math.floor(i_value(key, TET, highest))
print(f"Number of notes above = {notes_above}")

notes_below = - math.ceil(i_value(key, TET, lowest))
print(f"Number of notes below = {notes_below}")

print(f"Total number of notes = {notes_below+notes_above+1}")

equal_temper = [ ]
for i in range(-notes_below, notes_above+1):
    # We have to add 1 to notes_above since range is NOT inclusive of the ending term.
    equal_temper.append(note_value(key, TET, i))

print(*equal_temper, sep="\n")
```

Some notes: 
`Log(x)/Log(B)` gives log base B of X, no matter what the original base of Log is. This is why we divide by `math.log(2)` in our `i_value` function -- it gives us log base 2 of `N/key`.

The letter `f` used right before a string indicates a format string and will replace anything within `{}` with the whatever it evaluates to. For example, `x=5; print(f"My x is {x}")` will print `My x is 5`. This shorthand feature is new to python 3.6. If you're using a version prior to python 3.6, then you will need to replace the format statements with the longer version: `print("Number of notes above = {}".format(notes_above))`

The very last print statement at the end uses `*` to 'unpack' the list of `equal_temper` notes and then prints them with a newline (`\n`) between each element.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply write something like

```
while lowest <= note <= highest:
  ...
```

That way you make the reverse of the condition in the if-statement the condition for the while loop and get rid of the hardcoded boolean value.

Edit:
I have made some slight modifications to your code and came up with this:

```
def get_equal_tempers(multiplier):
    tempers = list()
    note = 20
    i = 1
    while lowest <= note <= highest:
        note = key * (2 ** (1 / TET)) ** (i*multiplier)
        if note > highest or note < lowest:
            break
        tempers.append(note)
        i += 1
    return tempers



highest = 20000 
lowest = 20

key = 440 
TET = 12

equal_temper = [key] 
equal_temper += get_equal_tempers(1) 
equal_temper += get_equal_tempers(-1)

equal_tempered = sorted(equal_temper)
for i in range(len(equal_temper)):
  print(equal_tempered[i])
```

When i run it on my machine, it produces the same output as your code. Can you please check?

Comment: Yes! That worked. I did also have to define "note" outside of (before) the loop so that it doesn't throw a "NameError."

Comment: There is one small problem with that solution though, it will add one number lower than and one number higher than our specified range. Does anyone know how to correct that small error?

Comment: @JustinBrunkow have you tried replacing the <= operators with simple < operators? I did not actually run your code. Might be I messed up there...

Comment: yes I did! Thankyou for the recommendation, but that produced the same result.